# extracting solution, algorithm from DecisionTree

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as DTS
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(20,size=1000).reshape(200,5)
b = []
for i in a:
    if i[2] == 5:
        b.append(1)
    else:
        b.append(0)

b = np.array(b).reshape(200,1)

t1,t2,y1,y2 = tts(a,b)

l = DTS()
l.fit(t1,y1)
print(l.score(t2,y2))
```

There are five features randomly generated. If third column(middle column) has 5 as value, the output is 1, else 0. I tested DecisionTreeClassifier and it seems it works. I have also made some predictions and it seems it works. Now my question is: How do I get an algorithm out for a solution out? Let's assume this is real data and I have no idea how inputs are co-related to output, however DecisionTreeClassifier would work on this dataset. Thanks

Comment: You want the decision path from your `DecisionTreeClassifier`? Sounds like you should use [`decision_path`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.decision_path).

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. But I really don't understand what this tells me? I receive tuples(int,int) with 1... How to understand this?

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and reformat your question accordingly.